# Append string to txt-iOS

Tags: ios

As shown code below, I am attempting to save all string comes. However, even though it displays txt created but there is no txt created. refer this question [Adding string on existing txt file -iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682468/adding-string-on-existing-txt-file-ios)

```
 -(void)saveData:(NSString*)data
    {
        NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.txt",documentDirectory,1];
            NSString *content=data;
            NSFileHandle *fileHandler= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
            [fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
            [fileHandler writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [fileHandler closeFile];
            NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
    }
```

Comment: You're going pretty far of of your way to write a txt file.  Convert your string to NSData and use `-writeToFile:aomtic:error:`

Comment: you mean [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

Comment: it creates txt file but how I then append string on this generated txt file?

Comment: Yes.  I wrote that off the top of my head, sorry.  When you convert the string, it is already in the file.  You know that's what files are, right?  Data objects with an extension to identify them to the system.

Comment: can I create a txt file and then append string in one method?